# C++ Implementation to Trim Char Array of Leading/Trailing White Space Not Working As Expected

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a simple and safe way to trim a char array of both leading and trailing white space. It works to remove the leading white space, but isn't working for the other side. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
template<size_t charCount>
void strtrim_safe( char (&output)[charCount] ) {
  char *ptr = output;
  size_t n = charCount;
  size_t start = 0;
  size_t end = 0;

  // Find the start and end position of trimmed string
  while ( n-- != 0 && *ptr != 0 ) {
    if ( *ptr == 32 ) {
        if ( end == 0 ) {
            start++;
        } else {
            break;
         }
    } else {
        end++;
    }

    ptr++;
  }

  // Shift the char array 
  for ( int i = start, j =  0; i < end, j < charCount; i++, j++ ) {
      output[j] = output[i];
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT1:
Thanks to your input, I think I have fixed the issue. The following code in place of the code under Shift the char array seems to do the trick:

```
// Shift the char array 
for ( int i = start, j =  0; i < end + start && j < charCount; i++, j++ ) {
    output[j] = output[i];
}
output[end] = 0;
```

Tested with trailing white space only, leading white space only, white space on both sides, and of course, no white space. So far, so good

EDIT2:
In order to account for possible interior spaces, I did the checking within the while loop and came up with this:

```
template<size_t charCount>
void strtrim_safe( char (&output)[charCount] ) {
   char *ptr = output;
   size_t n = charCount;
   size_t start = 0;
   size_t end = 0;

   // Find the start and end position of trimmed string
   while ( n-- != 0 && *ptr != 0 ) {
      if ( *ptr == 32 ) {
        if ( end == 0 ) {
            start++;
        } else {
          size_t endTmp = end;
          while ( *ptr == 32 && n-- != 0 && *ptr != 0 ) {
            end++;
            ptr++;
          }
        if ( *ptr == 0 || n == 0 ) {
          end = endTmp;
        } else {
          end++;
        }
      }
    } else {
      end++;
    }

    ptr++;
  }

  // Shift the char array 
  for ( int i = start, j =  0; j < end + start && j < charCount; i++, j++ ) {
    output[j] = output[i];
  }
  output[end] = 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add `start` to `end` otherwise `end` won't take any leading spaces into account.

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma between those conditions in the `for` loop.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I added that to the code, but it isn't the fix for the trailing spaces.

Comment: I think you're problem is that you don't know if the first space at the end of the string is a trailing space or not, so you have to calculate the position of the null termination byte and double back from there to get `end`.

Comment: @JustKevin Thanks for the input. I definitely forgot to null terminate at end when appropriate.

Comment: What happens if the string is "I AM". Doesn't the string break on the first space while end is 0?

Comment: [Closely related](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59243/489).

Answer (score 7):

```
void strtrim(char* str) {
    int start = 0; // number of leading spaces
    char* buffer = str;
    while (*str && *str++ == ' ') ++start;
    while (*str++); // move to end of string
    int end = str - buffer - 1; 
    while (end > 0 && buffer[end - 1] == ' ') --end; // backup over trailing spaces
    buffer[end] = 0; // remove trailing spaces
    if (end <= start || start == 0) return; // exit if no leading spaces or string is now empty
    str = buffer + start;
    while ((*buffer++ = *str++));  // remove leading spaces: K&R
}
```

Comment: I like that you didn't need a flag for the leading space indicator.  It's a little tough on the eyes, though.

Comment: Vertical space can be added for clarity in an editor. Here, it's best to use as little vertical space as possible, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're problem is that you don't know if the first space at the end of the string is a trailing space or not, so you have to calculate the position of the null termination byte and double back from there to get `end`.

What if you have an interior space as in `"    hello there.    "`?

I think that your algorithm is wrong.  If you want to calculate start and the null-termination byte on a single while loop that's fine, the code looks like this:

I see your point about adding `start` to `end`, but it missed the interior space clause.

```
size_t i = 0;
bool flag_leadingspace = TRUE; // effectively TRUE
while( *ptr != 0 )
{

    if( *ptr == 32 ) // space
    {
        if( flag_leadingspace ) start ++; // got it.
    }
    else // ---> *ptr != 32 // non-space
    {
        flag_leadingspace = FALSE; // effectively FALSE
    }
    ptr++; i++;
}

ptr--;         // since *ptr === 0
charCount = i; // you're character count 
end = i-1;     // we start looking for the end at i-1;

while( *ptr == 32 )
{ // if there is no trailing space, then end is already set
  //   and the block is skipped.

    end --;
    ptr --;
}

// Shift the char array // from above 
for ( int i = start, j =  0; i < end; i++, j++ )
{
    output[j] = output[i];
}

// and corrected to null terminate.
output[j] = 0;
```

well almost a copy paste, but you get the point.  I hope that works for the function.

Comment: @JustinKevin Good point about the interior space. I didn't see this before making EDIT1. Side note: charCount should NEVER be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

I have designed three functions for trimming the spaces of a `char*` array, at left, at right and at both ends, by returning a pointer to the new processed string.

```
char* LTrim(char* szX)
{
    if(' '==szX[0]) while(' '==(++szX)[0]);
    return szX;
}

char* RTrim(char* szX)
{
    int i = strlen(szX);
    while(' '==szX[--i]) szX[i] = 0;
    return szX;
}

char* Trim(char* szX)
{
    szX = LTrim(szX);
    szX = RTrim(szX);
    return szX;
}
```

An example of their usage and implementation is [here](http://rextester.com/WBDEA49767)

Of course, they aren't working with `const char*` but are very useful especially for processing fixed-width text tables.

Comment: Yes, one can compose `LTrim` and `RTrim` to `Trim`, but doing so is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

a more simple version of a function to trim leading and trailing spaces:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void trim(char** arg, char c)
{
    char* p = *arg; // preserve the original string
    while(*p++); p--; while(c==*--p) *p = 0; // deleting trailing spaces
    while(c==*(*arg)++); (*arg)--; // ignoring leading spaces
}

int main()
{
    char* pszX[] = {
     "             THE QUICK brown fox 012        ",
       "           THE QUICK brown fox 012",
                  "THE QUICK brown fox 012               ",        
                 " THE QUICK brown fox 012 ",
                 " THE QUICK brown fox 012",    
                  "THE QUICK brown fox 012 ",        
                  "THE QUICK brown fox 012",                
                    };
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<7; i++)
    {
        char* arg = strdup(pszX[i]);
        trim(&arg, ' ');
        printf("\"%s\"\n", arg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It can be adapted, to trim only leading or only trailing spaces too.